# Chrome fails to view a html file

Tags: html

I have set up a website which is visible from FF but not from Safari nor Chrome. I thought it is because of faulty WordPress install but obviously it is not because I have added a test.html in the root, FF views it but Chrome gives an error.

Never happened before, tried Google but found generally app or html problems causing the issue.

Comment: It will help to know what error you are getting. Perhaps a screenshot can make things clear if there is no error.

Comment: I see the same page in FF and Chrome (Windows). Try clearing cache, disabling extensions etc.

Comment: Jhon Conde, thank you for your correction and clean up. I will be more careful next time when I open a topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems you probably ran a cached instance of your site in FF while Chrome is actually telling you the you truly do not have a site being rendered. I checked your url in FF and I got the same as in Chrome (zip, nada, zilch, zero, nothing, absence of something, etc) :)

1. check your site CNAME and DNS. You may not be directing the site to the domain properly.

Right now you have these:
  NS1.NATROHOST.COM
  NS2.NATROHOST.COM

Are these it?

1. check your htaccess file. You may be blocking your entire site out

Comment: You got "nothing" in both browsers? I get a valid, but basic, page in both browsers! Maybe there is a problem with DNS (propagation)...?

Comment: ...although I see the same nameservers that you are seeing.

Comment: Strangely it worked. All I did was to go to DNS management, added a dot after NS, got an error and clicked cancel. Maybe it refreshed or triggered something